# useEffect function inside context unaware of state changes inside itself

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, use-effect, react-context

I am building a messaging feature using socket.io and react context;
I created a context to hold the conversations that are initially loaded from the server as the user passes authentication.

```
export const ConversationsContext = createContext();

export const ConversationsContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const { user } = useUser();
    const [conversations, setConversations] = useState([]);
    const { socket } = useContext(MessagesSocketContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(conversations);
    }, [conversations]);

    useEffect(() => {
       if (!socket) return;

    socket.on("userConversations", (uc) => {
        let ucc = uc.map((c) => ({
            ...c,
            participant: c.participants.filter((p) => p._id != user._id)[0],
        }));
        setConversations([...ucc]);
    });

    socket.on("receive-message", (message) => {
        console.log([...conversations]);
        console.log(message);
        setConversations((convs) => {
            let convIndex = convs.findIndex(
                (c) => c._id === message.conversation._id
            );
            let conv = convs[convIndex];
            convs.splice(convIndex, 1);
            conv.messages.unshift(message);
            return [conv, ...convs];
        });
    });
}, [socket]);

return (
    <ConversationsContext.Provider
        value={{
            conversations,
            setConversations,
        }}
    >
        {children}
    </ConversationsContext.Provider>
);
};
```

The `conversations` state is updated with the values that come from the server, and I have confirmed that on the first render, the values are indeed there.

Whenever i am geting a message, when the `socket.on("receive-message", ...)` function is called, the `conversations` state always return as `[]`. When checking devTools if that is the case I see the values present, meaning the the `socket.on` is not updated with the `conversations` state.

I would appreciate any advice on this as I`m dealing with this for the past 3 days.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, for one, I believe the `console.log([...conversations])` part will always log `[]` because of what's known as a "[stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/)" - your `useEffect` call does not depend on `conversations`, it only depends on `[socket]`, so the value of `conversations` is never updated after the initial effect runs. Other than the logging being broken, does the actual application work?

Comment: It does not. The context does not reflect changes no matter what I do.

Comment: TBH I don't see any issue of stale closure in this code (beside that single line of console.log that logs conversations). The update function is not dependent on it directly and will get the fresh state from react when the update occur. I do however see a potential state mutation issue with this line `convs.splice(convIndex, 1)` and `conv.messages.unshift(message)` try using `slice` / `map` / `filter` etc.. instead and don't mutate the array and object

Answer (score 0):

You can take "receive-message" function outside of the useEffect hook and use thr reference as so:

```
const onReceiveMessageRef = useRef(); 
onReceiveMessageRef.current = (message) => {
    console.log([...conversations]);
    console.log(message);
    setConversations((convs) => {
        let convIndex = convs.findIndex(
            (c) => c._id === message.conversation._id
        );
        let conv = convs[convIndex];
        convs.splice(convIndex, 1);
        conv.messages.unshift(message);
        return [conv, ...convs];
    });
};

useEffect(() => {
       if (!socket) return;

    socket.on("userConversations", (uc) => {
        let ucc = uc.map((c) => ({
            ...c,
            participant: c.participants.filter((p) => p._id != user._id)[0],
        }));
        setConversations([...ucc]);
    });

    socket.on("receive-message", (...r) => onReceiveMessageRef.current(...r));
}, [socket]);
```

let me know if this solves your problem